# Why not use IP address for images?

Tags: support

I was trying to insert a link to an image in my question, but it says

> Links cannot contain <IP address> (try a nonnumeric domain or wrap it in a code block)

[image]

Because it should show up as an image, I don't want it to be a code block. It should help people understand my question, not make it harder.

I also don't want to misuse one of my domain names just for SuperUser, because it simply doesn't belong to one of the domains. Yes, I know, I could simply register on one of the thousands of image hosters, but why should I do that if I have my own server?

What's wrong in linking an IP address? Actually I think it worked before, because I see that I have uploaded other pictures there already (but maybe it was for StackOverflow).

Comment: Why not embed the picture in the question?

Comment: Ideally, you should be using SU's image upload functionality. That way, you won't break the post when the images get removed from your own server.

Comment: @Raystafarian: I am trying to embed using `![comment](URL)` syntax

Comment: No that's a link. I meant upload like @Bob said.

Comment: @Bob: ok, uploading works (see my updated question above). I think I'll use this approach from now on. But anyway, the question remains. Using a domain name is allowed, but it could also be broken if I unregister the domain.

Comment: I'm not sure enough about this to post a proper answer, but it's *much* easier for a reference to an IP address to break rather than to a domain. Doesn't even require a service to disappear, just a minor infrastructure change. Sure, links to images hosted on domains might break as well, but it strikes a balance between requiring `i.stack.imgur` and letting anyone link anywhere. Plus, users might link to files on their local network, not understanding the limited access, and use of IP addresses is much more likely there.

Comment: IMHO the site should only ever accept embedded images from i.stack.imgur.com, the official image host of SE that permanently keeps all images linked to by SE content. It's a potential security issue (CSRF/XSS/HPP, for instance) to allow someone to make anyone who visits a question on SE to perform an arbitrary HTTP request anywhere on the internet. Not all HTTP GET requests are idempotent and harmless, and not all web apps are secure by design.

Comment: See [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131639/are-ip-address-links-valid-in-posts) for some more information on this decision. You're welcome to raise the issue of allowing image links like this, but since there's an easy and better way, I doubt any action will be taken.

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the reason is 'security' and more importantly the prevention of link rot. What if you move servers? You can't point the ip address to your new server as easily as you could a domain name.

In addition, SE has an agreement with imgur to host images - this means images you have uploaded here *never* go down. Its much better than brittle personal hosting.